# How to Enable Cookies in UIWebView for iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, oauth, uiwebview

I have an app that uses Instagram Integration.  The App has been in the App Store for a few months with multiple version all working fine.  Suddenly, the latest version I submitted to Apple was rejected because apple doesn't like the fact that Safari is launched for a User to Login to Instagram.  As per their words, they care about the user experience.

The problem is I need to request an Access Token and that is how I know it has to be done.  Since my App was rejected, I can't be the only one who may have faced this so I thought I should ask.  Does any one know of some other method perhaps I don't know of whereby you can authenticate a users Instagram and get the required Access Token, without Launching Safari?

EDIT #1: The only other option I can think of is to use a UIWebView within my app to open the Instagram authentication process. I tried this and it just seems to be mad slow and the callback process to my app doesn't seem to initiate.  So I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.

EDIT #2: Doing more research as to why the Instagram login is not working in my UIWebView, it seems to be something with how the UIWebView handles Cookies, apparently it does not recognize Cookies or something along those lines.  I still don't know what exactly to do to fix this, so if anyone has a solution please provide.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [this](https://github.com/crino/instagram-ios-sdk) is something that could help you. You haven't given many infos about your app so I can't think of something outside the box, but try looking into [Instagram iPhone Hooks](https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/) and see if you can use them to trigger login when the user does something.

Comment: I'm already doing this. This doesn't really answer this question.  My App users Instagram Hooks to do all sorts of things already.  I'm asking about Authenticating a user and receiving the Access Token required by instagram.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure this can be optimized a little bit, I probably do not need the for loop.  But either way, I've spent almost a day on this issue and just don't want to touch it anymore since I was finally able to get this to work by doing the following before loading the UIWebView:

```
var req = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
var cookies = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies as! [NSHTTPCookie]

var reqCookies:[AnyObject] = []

for aCookie in cookies {

    reqCookies += [aCookie]

}

var headers = NSHTTPCookie.requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies(reqCookies)

self.webView.loadRequest(req)
```

Comment: where did you use headers here ?